Enriched functor categories as $V$-objects
Under "Enriched functor categories" at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end#enriched_functor_categories it is claimed that for $V$-enriched categories $C$ and $D$ the functor category $[C,D]$ (of $V$-enriched functors) is again $V$-enriched and moreover that $[C,D](F,G)$ as a $V$-object is computed via the usual end $\int_{c\in C}D(Fc,Gc)$. I am wondering why those two are indeed isomorphic as objects in $V$? For a more concrete example, if I take any topologically enriched category $C$ and consider $[C,\mathrm{Top}](F,G)$ then the underlying set will be a subset $[C,\mathrm{Top}](F,G)\subseteq \prod_{c\in C}\mathrm{Top}(Fc,Gc)$ and I suppose that the topology will be the subset topology (although I do not have a convincing argument). So my question is: how do I determine the topology on $[C,\mathrm{Top}](F,G)$ and why is it homeomorphic to that of the end?

The hom-object of the functor category is defined to be the end. A justification this is appropriate is that this defines a symmetric closed monoidal structure on the 2-category of $V$-enriched categories. A good reference for this is §2 of Kelly's Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory. You can then check what the end gives you in concrete cases to check that it matches your intuition, e.g. recovering the usual definition of functor category for $V = \mathrm{Set}$.
